Search nested Object Array with fusejs
I want to implement a fuzzy search. I use fuse.js for this. The problem is that when I search for 'banking', for example, all other terms with 'B' are also displayed.
This is my code:
const data = [{
    letter: "A",
    items: [
      { title: "Authentification", }, 
    ],
  },
  {
    letter: "B",
    items: [
      { title: "Banking", },
      { title: "Banana", },
      { title: "Basketball", },
    ],
  },
];

onChange = {
  async(e) => {
    const { value } = e.currentTarget;
    const Fuse = (await import ("fuse.js/min")).default;
    const fuse = new Fuse(formattedGlossar || [], {
      keys: ["items.title"],
      distance: 0.7,
    });

    value === "" ?
      setItems(formattedGlossar) :
      setItems(fuse.search(value).map((item) => item.item));
  }
}

This is the result I get from the search, when I search for 'Banking':
[{
  "item": { 
    "letter": "B",
    "items": [
      { "title": "Banking", },
      { "title": "Banana", },
      { "title": "Basketball", }
    ]
  },
  "refIndex": 1,
  "score": 2.220446049250313e-16
}]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, because I've followed the documentation exactly.
https://www.fusejs.io/examples.html#nested-search

I’m not an expert on fuse.js, but the documentation you linked does not have an example with multiple items grouped under a single label — maybe that’s where the problem lies.
It seems to be simply returning whatever item that matches your search criterion, which in this case is the B-item because one of its items.titles matches the item.title you’ve provided.
In other words, you’re implicitly expecting it to dissect the resulting items for you, while all it’s supposed to be doing is only find and return the entire matching item, not the subpart of it that matches — which is exactly what it seems to be doing in the example you provided.
If you had two distinct B-items, one for ‘Banking’ and one for ‘Barking’ or ‘Spanking’ or ‘ Baking’, it would possibly return just the ‘Banking’ one and not the others, just as you would expect. But in your case, the “others” are just alternative item.titles of the same overall (matching) item.
Again, it’s the first time I see fuse.js, and the above is merely my intuitive educated guess.
———-
If you want only the matching subpart of the overall matching item to be returned, and if fuse.js does not have such functionality built in, all you have to do is simply use another layer of processing/filtering to map/transform the resultset items into “stripped” versions of the full originals.
If this is a one time need only for a single data structure shape (or perhaps just a small number thereof), it might suffice to simply code one-off stripping functions for each case of a data structure shape. But if this ends up being more of a pattern applicable to a wider range, or dynamic number, of types of searches/data shapes, you might be better off extending fuse.js, or requesting fuse.js developers to extend it for you, or help you extend it, if they see general value in such addition to the library.
Alternatively, you can just write a generic stripping procedure and stick it in one of your own generic library modules for reuse.
